# How to deal with the FinderException while migrating EJB 2 CMP entity beans to EJB 3 JPA entity?

Tags: jpa, ejb, entity, cmp

I'm migrating an `EJB2` application and I don't know how to deal with the `FinderException` thrown by `EJB2 CMP` entity beans because in some business methods there was logic code implemented in catch clause of `FinderException`.

```
    public void myMethod(){

        ...

        try {
               File file = fileHome.findFile(inFile);

            } catch (FinderException e) {
                // Other logic
            } 

    }
```

Now File is an `EJB 3 JPA` entity and there is no need to throw the `FinderException` on the `findFile(...)` method

Is there any replacement of the `FinderException` so I can keep the business logic of myMethod?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this for a while.
The answer is yes, `javax.persistence.NoResultException` is what you are looking for.

In case of my migration to ejb3 I have substituted `FinderException` with `NoResultException` on every occurence. It does not change logic as long as your code in `try` block is going to call entity manager through named queries eg. `entityManager.createNamedQuery("YourEntity.findById").setParameter(1, id).getSingleResult()` since `EntityManager::find` won't throw `NoResultException`.

Hope that helps.